# Hibernate update query : how to set a default value?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have two entity classes

```
class User { 
    Integer userId;
    String userName;
    UserType userType;
}
```

and

```
class UserType {
    Integer typeId;
    String type;
    Set<User> userList;
}
```

How can I set `new UserType()` in all `user.userType` where `user.userType=null` through HQL update query?

I am new in hibernate.

Comment: Read the **Update Query Example** section of this link: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-query-examples-hql/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
UserType userType = /* code to get already persisted userType */;

Query query = session.createQuery("update User u set u.userType = :newType where u.userType is null");
query.setParameter("newType", userType);
int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: thanks Spaeth, i was only thinkig about query.setString and query.setInterger to set id and username